# Chinese character in URL with Java

Tags: java, encoding, character, cjk

I used the following line in Firefox's URL field :

`http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=你`

This line was generated by my Java program.

The last Chinese character in the URL field sometimes became: `%C4%E3`  [Correct]

Other times it became: `%E4%BD%A0` [Incorrect]

I tried to use the URL with IE.  It shows up still as `你`, but the result page search field shows the character as `浣`. Could this be a UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding problem? How do I get the correct code `%C4%E3` from the char `你` with my Java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[URLEncoder.encode(string, encoding)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: The proper encoding is probably something like GB3212 or so. What the OP is seeing sometimes is UTF-8 (E4 BD A0).

Comment: looks like baidu is expecting GBK encoding.